# PowerBI unable to display image for Chiclet Slicer

Tags: analytics, business-intelligence, powerbi

So I've started using Microsoft's latest BI tool, PowerBI. I am very interested using the chiclet slicer custom visualisation module and include logos on the dashboard so that relevant data is filtered when clicked on a particular company logo. 
I have added an ImgURL field in the Region table as and the URL of the website maps to the Region values. However for some reason I am not able to display the image instead the URL is displayed. See screenshots below. How can I make it to display the image instead of the URL. What am I doing wrong? Pls see screenshots below.

[image]

If I click on London, the corresponding rows are filtered i.e. clipartbest.com website is only displayed (as expected) as below, however it doesn't bring through the image:

[image]

I've tried this with different URL links and can't seem to get it work. Any ideas? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Under Data Modeling, have you marked them as Image URL.

Comment: @Vasim Yes Data Type is Text and Data Category is ImageURL

Answer (score 1):

This is solved now. You need to drag a field in the 'Values' section otherwise the images won't be displayed.